# Bash function give as parameter -> ssh archive remote folder in local archive.tar.gz -> echo "test" also packed in tar file

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Hi I have a bash function:

```
function echoAndExecArgs 
{

echo -e "\n\n======== command: $@  ========"
$@

}
```

It echoes the command and all its parameters to stdout and executes it.

Now I give the following command:

```
ssh root@remoteMachine tar -czvf- /someFolder 2>> sterr.log | dd of=archive.tar.gz
```

The problem ist that the string `"\n\n======== command: $@  ========"` gets also written into the beginning of my `archive.tar.gz` file.

If I do `xxd -l 100 archive.tar.gz` I see that the string `"\n\n======== command: $@  ========"` is written at the beginning of the file. This of course leads to the problem that the file is corrupted and cannot be extracted as usual.

My question is: How is it possible to give my ssh command as parameter to the function `echoAndExecArgs` that it only redirects the actual file output of the tar command into the file `archive.tar.gz` and not all std outputs of the whole function?

This approach gives the same wrong result:

```
ssh user@host "tar -zcf - /someFolder" > archive.gz
```

Comment: `stout` probably just a typo, but just in case it should be "stdout", meaning "standard output". same for `sterr` that should be "stderr".

Comment: Note that you rarely want `$@` inside a larger quoted string. Unquoted on the next line, it is no different from unquoted `$*` and certainly *not* what you want.

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be output redirected to pipe, maybe try

```
echo -e "..." > /dev/tty
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write to stderr in your function:

```
echoAndExecArgs() {
    printf "\n\n======== command: %s ========\n" "$*" >&2
    "$@"
}
```

- Better to use more portable `printf` instead of `echo -e`
- Quote `"$@"` when executing in shell